# Firebase async scheduler issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to both firebase and async javascript. I'm trying to create a scheduled task in firebase to fetch a bunch of rss URLs from a collection, parse it and store it inside another collection but I'm getting Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded at Object.callErrorFromStatus upon its execution.

```
const refreshRSS = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 30 mins').onRun(async context => {
    let newRSS = addRSS();
    return await newPodcasts;
});

addRSS = async () => {
    const newRSSFeed = new Array();
    let rssURLs = await db.collection('rssURLs').get();
    rssURLs.forEach(async rssURLsObject=>{
        rss = rssURLsObject.data();
        let rssData = await parser.parseURL(rss.url);             
        newRSSFeed.push(db.collection('rss').doc(encodeURIComponent(rss.url))
        .set(podcast));

    })
    return newRSSFeeds;
}
```

I also tried returning Promise.all(newRSS) inside refreshRSS but it throws another error stating:  is not iterable.
I'm not sure what exactly is firebase expectingas return parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have to resolve promise in loop, try to use map. This will work:

```js
const refreshRSS = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 30 mins').onRun(async context => {
    let newRSS = await addRSS();
    return await newPodcasts;
});

addRSS = async () => {
    const newRSSFeed = new Array();
    let rssURLs = await db.collection('rssURLs').get();
    let promise = rssURLs.map(async rssURLsObject=>{
        rss = rssURLsObject.data();
        let rssData = await parser.parseURL(rss.url);  
        let con = await db.collection('rss').doc(encodeURIComponent(rss.url)
        newRSSFeed.push(con)
        .set(podcast));

    })
    await Promise.all(promise)
    return newRSSFeeds;
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to use map to iterate over data provided by firebase. Getting the following error:
TypeError: rssURLs.map is not a function

Comment: rssURLs is not array?

Comment: My bad, the get() method returns a snapshot object. To get the array I need to use .docs. But even after doing that I'm still getting timeouts, the following is the error:
Error: Request timed out after 60000ms at Timeout.setTimeout (/workspace/node_modules/rss-parser/lib/parser.js:101:23)

Comment: Again my bad, in the function I resolved newRSSFeeds instead of promise. It's working now!